# why am I not getting values while executing but getting them while debugging?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

There is a issue I am facing for following code,

This below code works fine and when I put a debug pointer on the place But if I try to executing with out debug pointer it doesn't read properly so I don't get exact value. so this bring last saved value to this place.. is any synchornization related issue? 
    All I want a solution is this line should work while executing as how its working while debugging?

```
    if(session.getAttribute("lightingDesc")!=null)
   {
    lightingDesc=(String)session.getAttribute("lightingDesc");
   }
```

Found the root cause of above issue .. Here is the code  :           document.strikeoffForm.submit();
window.open('<%= baseURL %>/jsps/makeStrikeOffs/Print.jsp', "printStrikeoff");
its happening because of Asynchronous call.
the issue is I am doing like this ..  1. submitting form 2. opening new window to show the submitted value. But some time before submiting a form the 2 action happened . I think the solution in Ajax but I am not aware how to do.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What it doesn't read properly? Care to put outputs too.

Comment: A breakpoint won't change the output of code

Comment: We need to see more of your code. Problem lies somewhere else probably.

Comment: HI All this is the rest of the code on this part:                     <%
  String lightingDesc="";
System.out.println("tester1 :+session.getAttribute("lightingDesc"));
    if(session.getAttribute("lightingDesc")!=null)
{
lightingDesc=(String)session.getAttribute("lightingDesc");
}   
%>
<b>Lighting:  </b><%= lightingDesc %><br>

Comment: It's unclear from your question, what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and on which "place" you put a break point.

Comment: Please edit your question, if you want to clarify it (with additional code).

Comment: Double check that the code you are executing, is the same code you have in your debugger (i.e. recompile your code, to make sure). Most of my problems when debugging come from that.

Answer (score 2):

Is your application using threads? It may be possible that some other thread is putting this value in the session. Following scenarios occur during debug and run:

In case of run, this thread may get executed before the other thread puts the value, hence unable to find the value.

In case of debug, your IDE stops/blocks current thread, hence, the other thread  may get a chance to put the value and that may be the reason why you are getting the value in case of debug.

One of the solution is to use join() method of thread class so that this thread can wait until the producer thread puts the value.

Comment: Hi thanks for your valuable input ..Found the root cause of above issue .. Here is the code  :        document.strikeoffForm.submit();
window.open('<%= baseURL %>/jsps/makeStrikeOffs/Print.jsp', "printStrikeoff");                                 
its happening because of Asynchronous call.
the issue is I am doing like this ..  1. submitting form 2. opening new window to show the submitted value. But some time before submiting a form the 2 action happened . I think the solution in Ajax but I am not aware how to do.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to display the values which are being submitted? Or the result of processing after submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

Working in debugging is not a valid reason.

The most probable reason is  in some other place you are setting the `attribute value` again and that is after this line of code.

Comment: tis is the rest of the code.. I didn't set anything after this :                  <%
      String lightingDesc="";
                  System.out.println("tester1 :  "+session.getAttribute("lightingDesc"));
    if(session.getAttribute("lightingDesc")!=null)
    {
     lightingDesc=(String)session.getAttribute("lightingDesc");
    }   
%>
                 <b>Lighting:  </b><%= lightingDesc %><br>

Answer (score 0):

Hi All thanks for your all inputs. It may be the not proper way but for as of now its working fine so its good to me.. I given solution like this:

```
document.strikeoffForm.submit();           
<%  Thread.sleep(500)%>        
window.open('<%= baseURL %>/jsps/makeStrikeOffs/Print.jsp', "printStrikeoff");
```